Ultra precise vibrator triggering in any state of the phone
My Android app (Jetpack Compose) needs to trigger phone vibrator on a VERY PRECISE time (maximum delay of few milliseconds).
Vibrator must be triggered on any state of phone and app: phone woke up and app in foreground, phone in idle state and app in background, other app getting a lot of processor, ... I just want to tell to user "Please do not close app, but do what ever you want with your phone" :-)
For that, I use (see my code below) :

A Foreground Service, with phone call permission
A NTP clock that help me to compensate drift of local system hour
A function alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle() to set my alarm

It works pretty well, but in some cases (phone idle for a long time, lot of apps running, ...), vibrator starts with delay, that can reach several seconds, that is not good in my use case :-)
Do you see any other Android routines or tools I should use to make my vibrator trigger VERY precise ? Thanks!
<application>
...
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
        <service android:name=".VibrationService" android:exported="false" android:foregroundServiceType="phoneCall"/>
...
 </application>
 ...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_PHONE_CALL" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_OWN_CALLS" />

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        enableEdgeToEdge()
        setContent {
            Project4Theme {
                ScheduleVibrationAlarm(context = this)               
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ScheduleVibrationAlarm(context: Context) {
    var calendar by remember { mutableStateOf(Calendar.getInstance()) }
    var timeDifference by remember { mutableStateOf<Long?>(null) }

    Column(
    ) {
        Text(text = "Schedule Vibration Alarm")
        Button(onClick = {
            Thread {
                try {
                    // Get NTP time
                    val ntpClient = NTPUDPClient()
                    ntpClient.defaultTimeout = 10000
                    val inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("pool.ntp.org")
                    val timeInfo = ntpClient.getTime(inetAddress)
                    timeInfo.computeDetails()

                    // Get local system time
                    val localTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

                    // Get difference
                    val ntpTime = timeInfo.message.transmitTimeStamp.time
                    timeDifference = ntpTime - localTime

                    // Set vibrator alarm time (17:00 today)
                    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17)
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0)
                    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
                    calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (timeDifference!!.toInt()*-1))
                    val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
                    val intent1 = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
                    val pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
                    alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.timeInMillis, pendingIntent1)

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.e("NTP", "Fail on NTP get", e)
                }
            }.start()
        }) {
            Text(text = "Set Vibrator Alarm")
        }
    }
}

class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val vibrationIntent = Intent(context, VibrationService::class.java)
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(vibrationIntent)
        } else {
            context.startService(vibrationIntent)
        }
    }
}

class VibrationService : Service() {
    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {

        // Create a notif (if not, Android kill foreground service :)
        createNotificationChannel()
        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(this, "VibrationServiceChannel")
            .setContentTitle("Vibrator")
            .setContentText("Vibrator is running ")
            .build()

        // Start foreground service
        startForeground(1, notification)

        // Vibrate
        val vibrator = getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE) as Vibrator
        vibrator.vibrate(1000)

        // Stop service
        stopSelf()
        return START_NOT_STICKY
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    private fun createNotificationChannel() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            val serviceChannel = NotificationChannel(
                "VibrationServiceChannel",
                "Vibration Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
            )
            val manager = getSystemService(NotificationManager::class.java)
            manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel)
        }
    }
}


If you want ultra-precision you'd need to run an invasive battery draining foreground service with cpu-wakelock. However even though it should work in theory, in practice it doesn't as android OS got very good at culling such services.

What you want isn't going to be possible on an Android phone.  The OS is not a realtime OS, it's not designed to give that kind of time critical performance.  If you truly need this, you need to use a different operating system altogether.  Or you need to rethink your requirements-  why do you need these vibrations to be correct to the second?
